How to add layers to qgis2web
QGIS version: 3.20.0-Odense QGIS code revision: decaadbb31 Qt version: 5.15.2 Python version: 3.8.7
I was able to export a package that can be opened with the html link.  However, only one layer has been added and is visible (Open Street Map).  How do I add another data layer that is a point shape file?

Usually just include the layer and simply stylize it in QGIS, if you find problems upload your project and your data on the web and send the link here. So let's see what happens.

Is the point shapefile in your QGIS project but not being included when you export your qgis2web package? Or are you wanting to add your point shapefile after you export?

The point shapefile is in my QGIS project but not being included when I export the qgis2web package

Andrea, how/where do I upload my project and data to the web?  Good idea.

Where you prefer. In a website, Dropbox, GoogleDrive, OneDrive, Mega..

I uploaded files to GoogleDrive; the shp file that is the point layer, and also the export folder from using qgis2web.  Can I send the link to your email?

Sorry, I didn't see your reply. That google drive folder you can share as a link and you can paste it here, so I can acquire your files.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cA7hQjiO6yYo9UGbzyp8iTN7LKAeRbuV?usp=drive_link
